# Conda Install UnsatisfiableError

Tags: miniconda, fiona

I imagine a basic question that is exacerbating me.  While it concerns a package called Fiona, this is most likely a Conda question.  Could be any package. The package I want, Fiona has a handful of dependencies of which I have most installed in my Conda Env.  I need Numpy<=1.9.3 in my env so I found a Build String of Fiona satisfying that.
Ran `conda install "fiona=1.6.3=np19py27_1"` and I get this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package cligj conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> cligj
Package vc conflicts for:
python=2.7.14 -> vc=9
Package numpy conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> numpy=1.9
Package six conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> six
Package munch conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> munch
Package vs2008_runtime conflicts for:
python=2.7.14 -> vs2008_runtime
Package setuptools conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> setuptools
Package python_abi conflicts for:
python=2.7.14 -> python_abi=[build=*_cp27m]
Package pip conflicts for:
python=2.7.14 -> pip
Package click-plugins conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> click-plugins
Package pypy conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> pypy[version='<0a0']
Package gdal conflicts for:
fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> gdal==1.11.4
```

So basically EVERY dependency has a conflict.
Any ideas what is wrong and steps to fix this?  FYI the `fiona==1.6.3=np19py27_1 -> numpy=1.9` makes no sense because this Fiona build has a dependency for Numpy 1.9* and my conda env = 1.9.3?? I am on Python 2.7.14. Thanks - apologies in advance for my ignorance...

Comment: What does conda list show? wondering how complex your environment is currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that fiona is not able to find the correct mix of versions of the packages it needs and uses in your environment. fiona is definitely not compatible with numpy=1.9. If you are able to use a different version, you can try others, such as

```
conda install fiona=1.7.13 numpy=1.16.5
```

FYI, This is how I found the issue. I tried these 2 commands and found problems between fiona and numpy version 1.9

not working:

```
conda create --name py27a python=2.7  fiona numpy=1.9
```

working:

```
conda create --name py27a python=2.7  fiona=1.7.13 numpy=1.16.5
```